True windows width and height
I am working my way through a windows game programming book book which takes you through the fundamentals of Direct X, 2d and 3d.  It is going great and it is a great book.  I have gotten far and have now implemented and using Direct X and managed to get as far as to create function that plots pixels and draws a line in windows full screen mode.  I have also gotten as far as to use double buffering and flipping surfaces which is way cool.  But I have run into a issue I cant figure out.  Here goes (I hope I am explaining this correctly).
Background:  I am using the mode set in the display properties in windows.  My mode on this computer is 1920x1080 (32 bit).  I set this in the directx setMode function.  This works fine.
However, I have discovered that when i plot pixels or draw a line, my x, y coordinates become out of whack.  When I one to get the middle of the screen, I divide SCREEN_WIDTH by two which when drawing to positions the starting point wrong.  I have found out if I divide by three it works, but seems arbitrary to me.
So after reading post here I found out I can get the width and height at runtime using GetDesktopWindow() and Get WindowRect(...) to get the width and height properties.  And here is where I discovered the "BUG".
The screen width and height gives me 1280x720 (32bit).
So ok, if I use these values when a set x and y to plot and draw lines it all works as it should.  This was a bit funny so after reading more post online others have had the same issues and its suggested to call since GetWindowsDesktop() does not include the taskbar etc in its functionality.
-> SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE);
at the beginning of winapi entry.  I tried this and then the GetDesktopWindow() etc does return correct values, but then when I run the program the window gets out of whack displaying a boxed fullscreen window.
However, my question:
Is this a know issue and something one has to compansate for?  I can modify global screenwidth and height variables to use the values that GetWindowsDesktop gives and leave it at that.  It will work.
However I cant find out why this is happening and need to find out if this is a issue and if there is a way around this so I get the true x, y values by calling getDesktopWindow().  I find this whole thing being "buggy" and I am trying to figure out a way to correct this or if I have missed something big here.
Senhor Richard O'Otimo
Plot pixels at x, y position
Plotting at wrong coordinates
Tried correcting using screen width and height from GetWindowsDesktop()

Hi-DPI is not a bug or an issue, more a feature that you must understand as a developer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows It's difficult to understand exactly exactly what's your problem. see this How do I ask a good question? and this How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Yes, I am aware DPI ain't a bug and I can see that my question is a bit confusing.  The bottom line is I am using GetWindowDesktop to get the width and height of the screen and it's returning 1280 (width) and 720 (height) which is wrong, since my display is set at 1920 (width) andn 1080 (height).  I use the latter to set the mode when initializing DirextX and creating the main window.  So when I try to plot a pixel or draw a line I cant calculate correctly since I calculate with 1920x1080, while windows for some reasong is giving back 1280x720 through GetWindowsDesktop().

GetWindowDesktop is not a Windows API, so we don't know what this does, read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process, Windows is lying to you on purpose. Use a manifest with dpiAwareness set to PerMonitorV2 for example.

What version of the DirectX API are you learning? Is it DX9,  10, 11 or 12? Returning the current window width & height to the DX application after a window resize isn't difficult if done correctly and there are templates that show you how to do it properly. You are probably following advice from a non-expert source which is going about it the wrong way.
